# nodejs appinsight runtime instrument vs SDK

Tags: node.js, azure

According to AZure documents, there are two ways to use AppInsights. One is to Instrument your web app at run time. The other one is to use SDK in the source code. If I did both and in the source code I did not disable auto collection, will a request be collected twice?

In my case, I also called

```
appInsights.trackRequest(req,res);
```

at the start of an API processing function. And in the AZure portal page for AppInsights, I saw two records as the following:

```
> Operation  Name            Average   Count 
> GET       /route           30.22 ms    9 
> GET       /api/bus/route   0 ms        9
```

In my nodejs, the path should be /api/bus/route.

In another test, I remove the SDK from nodejs source code, just use the runtime instrument, the /api/bus/route data is still collected, but the average time is 0.

How to explain these?

Comment: According the document at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-nodejs/, actually there are two steps to integrate AI, not two options.

Comment: [https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now/](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now/) says You have a choice of three ways to apply Application Insights to your .NET web applications:  Build time, run time and both. I just realized that this is for .NET web applications. So for Node.js, there is actually just one option with the two steps as described in your link, right?

Comment: It's fine what ever the AI is for .Net web applications, it will also work for your node.js applications. You can follow https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-nodejs/ on local, create a simple nodejs server and integrate the AI SDK for node.js. You will have a clearer insight of the progress.